# how to get inserted value type

Tags: jquery, types

Using jQuery [.type](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/) I am trying to get the type of inserted value.
For example if I enter the following in a text box

- `02/10/2012` then its type is `date`
- `my test` then its type is `string`
- `123` then its type `number`

This is my code but it is not getting expected results, only `string`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.type demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Type <b></b>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#input').on('blur',function(){
    var text = $('input').val();
    if(text!==null) {
      alert(text);
      var t = jQuery.type(text); 
      alert(t);
    }
    else {
      alert('get');
    }
  });
});
</script>
<input type='text' id='input'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well... what results is it giving?

Comment: All input values are string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All input values are string

Here is a start

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2w6jF/)

```
function myType(str) {
  if (str === undefined) return "undefined";
  if (str === null) return "null";
  if (str.length===0) return "empty string";
  if (!isNaN(str) && /\d/.test(str)) return "number";
  if (Date.parse(str)) return "parsable date";
  return "string";
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('blur',function(){
    var text =$(this).val();
    var t = myType(text); 
    window.console && console.log(text,t);
  });
});
```

Comment: and whats about time and datetime

Comment: Date.parse(str) will handle many formats. What is missing you will need to code

Comment: your answer is perfect but now i want to check regex pattern for what? like `/\d/` this is for `number` /[a-z]/ -> this for string `/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/` -> this is for date.

Comment: like in textbox enter any type of pattern. this pattern created for what Date,Time,String,Number...etc

Comment: Yes, add all the regexes you want before the return string. But what is time? 1:30pm or 13:30:00 or both?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation very clearly states, `.type()` retrieves the type of the object you give it.

An input's value is always a string. It's up to you to determine whether that string is a number (maybe with `isNaN(text)`), or a date (regex is probably best here) etc.

Comment: any example for this regex??

Comment: @user2496644 No, because anyone who reads a basic regex tutorial should be able to do this.